# NPM Factory-Bot/Girl how to export a factory definition for use in my NodeJS specs?

Tags: node.js, testing, mongoose, jasmine, factory-bot

JS newbie here. I am using Jasmine to test a NodeJS application which uses MongoDB and Mongoose, and I would like to replace my static test fixtures with dynamic factories. https://github.com/ratson/factory-bot looks good to me.

However, all of the examples are from a single file and don't demonstrate exporting/importing between files, so I don't understand what to `modules.exports =` in order to use a factory in my specs.

I'm also using ES5 if that matters.

My question is: how do I export this definition?

`spec/factories/user.js`

```
const factory = require('factory-bot').factory;
factory.setAdapter(new FactoryBot.MongooseAdapter());
const User = require('../models/user');

factory.define('user', User, { 
  username: 'Bob',
  expired: false
});
factory.extend('user', 'expiredUser', {
  expired: true
 });
```

And then how do I use my export so that I can make `sampleUsers`?

`spec/controllers/user.js`

```
const reqs = require("../support/require")

describe("GET /users", () => {
  describe("index", () => {
    var data = {};

    var sampleUsers = factory.createMany('user', 5);

    beforeEach((done) => {
      reqs.Request.get(/users", (error, response, body) => {
        data.status = response.statusCode;
        data.body = JSON.parse(body);
        done();
      });
    });

    it("returns a 200 response status", () => {
      expect(data.status).toBe(200);
    });
    it("responds with the users collection", async () => {
          expect(data.body.users).toBe(sampleUsers);
    });
  });
});
```

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to require your factory definitions before using them.

Here's an example of what you could do:

`spec/factories/user.js`

```
const { factory } = require('factory-bot');
const User = require('../models/user');

factory.setAdapter(new FactoryBot.MongooseAdapter());

factory.define('user', User, { 
  username: 'Bob',
  expired: false
});

factory.extend('user', 'expiredUser', {
  expired: true
});
```

`spec/factories/index.js`:

```
const { factory } = require("factory-bot");

// Require factories to use with the exported object
require("./user.js");

module.exports = factory;
```

`spec/controllers/user.js`:

```
const factory = require("../../factories");

...

const sampleUsers = factory.createMany('user', 5);
```

The key difference between the example above and your sample code is the `index.js` file which requires `factory-bot` and all the factory definitions. By requiring the definitions, you will be able to use them.

If you `require('factory-bot')` directly instead of `require('spec/factories')`, you will need to require the factory definitions you want to use.